# Creating themes in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, jsr168

I want to make changes in look n feel of liferay, for that i have created themes using this link

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-the-4

Everything worked fine. I saw mesaage BUILD SUCCESSFULL at the end. But the problem is After clicking on Manage > Page > Look and Feel, i didnt see any theme created by me. So please can u tell me wats wrong with this?

War file is created at Desktop/LR/bundles/deploy/deep-gray-theme-6.1.1.1.war

Should i get(import) this war file from liferay GUI so that themes would be available?

Comment: It seems your theme is not deployed to server, otherwise there should not any war under deploy ...Have you seen logs for successfull deployment ? and make sure you are referring to same tomcat as placed at Desktop/LR/bundles/..

Answer (score 0):

Just check your build.properties file, and to verify check if the theme is present in webapps folder.